# Select only data which columns does not have specific corresponding values respectively

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBiiN.jpg)
**Select only data which columns does not have specific corresponding values.**

Table Values:

```
1   D675F009-6908-47A4-816A-AD25A68D8514    0   
2   7C96A948-B889-4630-BF67-2187ECFA37DC    1   
3   FD6DD4B4-6E5D-4282-B421-A849DB4B1D3E    1   
4   178B055F-45FF-4951-A9E2-3470B1DE25E9    1   
5   FD6DD4B4-6E5D-4282-B421-A849DB4B1D3E    0   
6   D675F009-6908-47A4-816A-AD25A68D8514    0   
7   59737584-F44F-4B42-AF9C-1550DFEC1EA5    1   
8   FD6DD4B4-6E5D-4282-B421-A849DB4B1D3E    1   
9   D675F009-6908-47A4-816A-AD25A68D8514    1   
10  7C96A948-B889-4630-BF67-2187ECFA37DC    0   
11  178B055F-45FF-4951-A9E2-3470B1DE25E9    1   
12  016FAF52-8FBF-4C9C-802D-CA9E13071719    0
```

- Don't select values which have:
  (D675F009-6908-47A4-816A-AD25A68D8514) have 1 respectively and
  (FD6DD4B4-6E5D-4282-B421-A849DB4B1D3E) have 1 respectively

```
Allow select values: 
(D675F009-6908-47A4-816A-AD25A68D8514) have 0
respectively and  (FD6DD4B4-6E5D-4282-B421-A849DB4B1D3E) have   0
respectively
```

- 

Expected Result::

```
    1   D675F009-6908-47A4-816A-AD25A68D8514    0
    2   7C96A948-B889-4630-BF67-2187ECFA37DC    1
    4   178B055F-45FF-4951-A9E2-3470B1DE25E9    1
    5   FD6DD4B4-6E5D-4282-B421-A849DB4B1D3E    0
    6   D675F009-6908-47A4-816A-AD25A68D8514    0
    7   59737584-F44F-4B42-AF9C-1550DFEC1EA5    1
    10  7C96A948-B889-4630-BF67-2187ECFA37DC    0
    11  178B055F-45FF-4951-A9E2-3470B1DE25E9    1
    12  016FAF52-8FBF-4C9C-802D-CA9E13071719    0
```

Comment: Use a `NOT EXISTS`? You aren't exactly clear here.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Select * from table where 
(is_active=1 and 
Participant_id NOT IN
('D675F009-6908-47A4-816A-AD25A68D8514', 'FD6DD4B4-6E5D-4282-B421-A849DB4B1D3E' )
) or 
is_active=0;
```